# Bookmark+ using a temporary file, despite having asked for a specific file

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

After typing `C-x r l` I get a buffer called `*Bookmark List*`
In this buffer I see:

```
Bookmark file:
/tmp/bmkp-temp/19236bkt
```

If I open help (i.e. press `h`), I see:

```
Bookmark file:  /tmp/bmkp-temp-19236bkt
Sorted:         
Filtering:      none
Marked:         0
Omitted:        0
Autosave bookmarks: no
Autosave list display:  yes
```

This is even though I have the following in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq bookmark-file "~/.emacs.d/bookmarks")
(setq bookmark-default-file "~/.emacs.d/bookmarks")
(setq bmkp-default-bookmark-file "~/.emacs.d/bookmarks")
(setq bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file nil)
```

Why is it using a different bookmark file from the one I specified?

I also noticed that when I load Emacs the following happens:

```
Emptying bookmark file `/tmp/bmkp-temp-23808OMn'...
Saving file /tmp/bmkp-temp-23808OMn...
Wrote /tmp/bmkp-temp-23808OMn
Emptying bookmark file `/tmp/bmkp-temp-23808OMn'...done
...
Helm completion enabled
Emptying bookmark file `/tmp/bmkp-temp-23808bWt'...
Saving file /tmp/bmkp-temp-23808bWt...
Wrote /tmp/bmkp-temp-23808bWt
Emptying bookmark file `/tmp/bmkp-temp-23808bWt'...done
...
```

Emacs goes on a spree deleting temporary bookmark files. ?

Comment: It seems to come from `bookmark+`, so you might like to contact its author.

Comment: /tmp/bmkp-temp-19236bkt contains temporary bookmarks, ~/.emacs.d/bookmarks contains persistent bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something, somewhere (e.g. check your .emacs file) has turned on `bmkp-temporary-bookmarking-mode`.  When that mode is on, any bookmarks you create are for the current session only -- they are not saved to your bookmark file.

And that means that your bookmark-file location settings are ignored. (Note, BTW, that `bmkp-default-bookmark-file` is a function, not a variable -- it is not something that you set.  And you don't need all of those bookmark-file settings; some are redundant: old names from old versions of Emacs bookmarking.)

I don't know why you are getting multiple temporary bookmark-file creations and saves. You didn't provide a complete recipe.  You should get only one such.  This is all I see in `*Messages*` in this regard, for instance:

```
  Emptying bookmark file `c:/DOCUME~1/me/LOCALS~1/Temp/bmkp-temp-5348su1'...
  Saving file c:/Documents and Settings/me/Local Settings/Temp/bmkp-temp-5348su1...
  Wrote c:/Documents and Settings/me/Local Settings/Temp/bmkp-temp-5348su1
  Emptying bookmark file `c:/DOCUME~1/me/LOCALS~1/Temp/bmkp-temp-5348su1'...done
```

It also appears that you have a lot of stuff going on (Helm etc.).  When trying to understand or debug a problem, it helps to narrow things down as much as possible.  Who can tell what other interactions might be involved here?

All of that said, my advice would be to *not* start out using the temporary bookmarking mode.  I would not suggest you use that until you are quite familiar with Bookmark+.  You can use temporary bookmarks without using this mode.

Here is the doc about using temporary bookmarks:
http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#toc55

Finally, as Stefan suggested, please follow up by email.  It's a lot easier for debugging/discussing things in detail.

Thx -- Drew

---

Update 2019-04-21:

I think what might have happened is that you quit Emacs with `bmkp-temporary-bookmarking-mode` enabled.  Although Bookmark+ (correctly) does not save the file of temporary bookmarks it was not preventing the recording of `bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file` from being updated to point to the temporary file. In your next Emacs session that temporary file (if it still existed) was loaded because of `bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file`.

That should be OK now.  Enabling `bmkp-temporary-bookmarking-mode` now resets `bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file` to `nil`, so if you quit with the temp mode still enabled, then when you load your bookmark file in a new session the file that is read is the value of `bookmark-default-file`.  (The value of `bookmark-default-file` is never changed, except by your
customizations.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were trying to use "bookmark-file bookmarks"? Or anyways, accidently hit `C-x p x`?

These are claimed to correspond, at [EmacsWiki: Bookmark Plus / Bookmark-File Bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#toc39), where they say, "`bmkp-set-bookmark-file-bookmark`, bound to `C-x p x`". For my Emacs, this is not true.

By typing `C-x p C-h`, I can check key-bindings that start with `C-x p`. I find

- `C-x p x` is bound to `bmkp-toggle-autotemp-on-set`, and
- `C-x p y` is bound to `bmkp-set-bookmark-file-bookmark`.

Then, the link should say `C-x p y` instead.

Comment: Those two key bindings have been just as they are now, and as you say they are, since 2011.  The typo in the doc that you cite was fixed back in 2014 (perhaps due to your post here; I don't recall). Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an old question, but since I had just the same problem and the other answers didn't help me I'll post my solution:

I'm using desktop files from desktop.el and the temporary mode was set there in the desktop file! Removing that setting from all my desktop files fixed the problem.

This might be handy:

```
find ~ -name .emacs.desktop -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l bmkp-temporary-bookmarking-mode
```